# How to merge this functionality with argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have this functionality:

```
import codecs
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
with codecs.open('/Users/user/Desktop/file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    spanish_stop_words = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print spanish_stop_words

from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
my_stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(spanish_stop_words)

tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=set(my_stop_words))
```

I was been struggling with the argparse [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) in order to understad where I can call the above "script" but I dont get how to merge it with argparse module. Also I would like to ask for the path to the user, in this line:

```
'/Users/user/Desktop/file.txt'
```

How can I merge this with a simply argparse schema?. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: `argparse` isn't a script. It is a module to help you write command-line interfaces. Why don't you try out the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html#id1) first?

Comment: I was not talking about argparse when I mentioned "script". I was talking about the lines I have previously...

Comment: Right, but to 'merge' `argparse` into that you'll still have to just import the module and use it to create the command-line interface. The tutorial shows you how.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry for the bad question... but I guess it was necesary to be penalized now, I understood what happened with the call to the functionality...belive me I hate doing this kind of questions...

Comment: I didn't vote on your post, but the documentation isn't *that* hard to follow, is it? People probably feel you haven't done your research here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way to get started alongside with the [`argparse` tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html):

```
import argparse
import codecs
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("stop_word_list", help="The stop word list")
args = parser.parse_args()

with codecs.open(args.stop_word_list, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    spanish_stop_words = [line.strip() for line in f]
    print spanish_stop_words

from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
my_stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(spanish_stop_words)

tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=set(my_stop_words))
```

Run your program with `python program.py` and it prints:

```
% python program.py 
usage: program.py [-h] stop_word_list
program.py: error: too few arguments
```

If you provide it with 1 argument, it is taken as a file to open as the stop word list

```
% python program.py mystopwordfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, by the way I dont get where argparse is looking for the desired file?. Where does this is happening?.

Comment: Thanks I am reading the tutorial.

Comment: argparse is not finding your file anywhere, it just provides a filename for your script in `args.stop_word_list` which is passed to `codecs.open()`